# How can highcharts linear scale or log scale button enabel and zoom in or out full page

Tags: highcharts

I create a highchart but some functionality is not enable in highchart.

1. linear scale button
2. log scale button
3. zoom button(zoom like when i click zoom button its cover full screen )

like this image
[image]

This image has 3 manor buttons.

Comment: Please post some Code that we can actually help you.

Comment: Also please fix "manor button".  I do not know what that is.  Did you mean "major buttons" ?

Comment: sir have a link for example https://coinmarketcap.com/charts/

Comment: its chart scale button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add additional buttons to your chart by exporting buttons configuration. To change axis scale, use update method with proper axis type. To apply full screen view, you can toggle some CSS class.

```
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    exporting: {
        buttons: {
            customButton: {
                text: 'Linear',
                onclick: function() {
                    this.yAxis[0].update({
                        type: 'linear'
                    });
                }
            },
            customButton2: {
                text: 'Logarithmic',
                onclick: function() {
                    this.yAxis[0].update({
                        type: 'logarithmic'
                    });
                }
            },
            customButton3: {
                text: 'Zoom',
                onclick: function() {
                    $('#container').toggleClass('modal');
                    this.reflow();
                }
            }
        }
    },
    rangeSelector: {
        inputPosition: {
            align: 'left'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512]
    }]
});
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w5Laobgc/

API Reference:

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#update

https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/exporting.buttons